# Mocking to multiple Interfaces

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

Is it possible to mock an object in a way that it fakes multiple interfaces implementations?
(Note: I am using "padraic's mockery" https://github.com/padraic/mockery)

Suppose I have a class Mysql, which implements Db_Interface and Configurable_Interface, and which I need to mock just to be able to test another class. I want to create a mock with another name, not Mysql (because it could change or disappear in the future, that's why we use interfaces, right?), so I don't want to do Mockery::mock('Mysql').

I know I could create it like Mockery::mock('Db_Interface') and it would pass the instanceof Db_Interface check. But how can I make it pass the check for the other interface too?

@Gordon
ok heres the code:

```
$m = Mockery::mock('Configurable_Interface');
var_dump($m instanceof Configurable_Interface); // true
var_dump($m instanceof Db_Interface); // false of course, since I don't know how to make a mock implement 2 interfaces
```

Comment: How is the type of the dependency enforced in the TestSubject?

Comment: I can't make that var_dump($my_mock instanceof Db_Interface) prints 'true'. That's all I need

Comment: @Happy can you please show some code.

Comment: I edited the post to add the code

Comment: @Happy sorry, this is not what I've been asking. How do you enforce the type of the dependency in the TestSubject. That is, how do you make sure mysql is in fact implementing these interfaces. And also, does your TestSubject require methods defined in both interfaces or does it only rely on methods from one interface?

Comment: @Happy the easiest would be if you could post the TestSubject class, e.g. the class you want to test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For anyone stumbling into this. In **Mockery**, you can call `Mockery::mock('firstInterface, secondInterface');` to mock an object wich needs to implement multiple interfaces.

Source: [Mockery README](https://github.com/padraic/mockery)

Comment: Had a little trouble with this, just make sure that the argument you pass in is ONE WHOLE STRING (`Mockery::mock('interface, interface2'`), and not TWO strings (`Mockery::mock('interface', 'interface2'`). Just in case you can't figure out why it's not working as well.

Comment: I tested this with Mockery 0.9.4 and the notation with two separate strings worked for me (`Mockery::mock('interface', 'interface2'`)

Answer (score 4):

`$this->getMockBuilder(['A', 'B'])->getMock();`

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT OP asked how to mock multiple interfaces with PHPUnit and the code above shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This thread comes out when the question is about phpspec !

So here is a way to do it with phpspec:

```
$prophecy = $this->prophesize(InterfaceA::class);
$prophecy->willImplement(InterfaceB::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a stub. create a class which implements the 2 interfaces. all methods with "return null". than create a mock with this stub.